# jboss remote deployment connection error

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss5.x, maven-cargo

I need to deploy war file to a remote `jboss5.1` using `cargo-maven2-plugin`. But when I get this error while executing `mvn cargo:deploy`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.5:deploy (default-cli) on project sample: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.5:redeploy failed: Cannot deploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.deployable.JBossWAR[sample.war]: Remote action failed: null (java.io.IOException: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [socket://xxx/?]) -> [Help 1]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the Jboss server running?

Comment: Could we see some pom.xml configuration and information about the jboss server (ports and so on...)